# how to get the access token expiration time in fb_graph?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I know how to get the access token.

```
access_token = @client.authorization.process_callback(params[:code], :redirect_uri => fb_redirect_url)
```

Can anybody suggest me how can I get expiration time also.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```
 @client.auth.expires_in
```

Thanks